# Whats wrong with my CSS/HTML in IE (even 9)

Tags: html, css

I have used modernizer & html5boilerplate's css. I haven't been good at designing/debugging for IE. I have been over reliant on FireBug I guess... whats wrong my my WIP http://jiewmeng.kodingen.com/demos/folio-wip/index.html

It looks like below in IE (even 9)

[image]

What it should look like ... in Firefox/Chrome

[image]

Comment: Does IE tester support JavaScript? The problem is as the answers have described, that IE doesn't style any element it doesn't 'recognise', but Modernizr, which you're using, [does create the elements in the DOM for them to work in IE](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#html5inie), so you should be fine

Comment: @Yi Jiang, just tried a simple alert, IETester runs JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Little know fact: you need to put the modernizr script on inside the head tag, otherwise IE doesn't know how to style the elements before rendering them. The webpage is perfectly fine declared as html5, lots of production websites are already doing this.

Answer (score 0):

IE simply doesn't support selectors like: a:link::before (you're using this in your menus).

Edit: heck, `<section>`, `<article>`?  IE anything?  Man this is all HTML5 stuff.  IE isn't going to support it at all (9 eventually, 6,7,8, never unless they use chromeframe!)

Comment: Hmm... I guess I've got to rethink in a more primitive way like IE. But shouldn't IE render HTML5 with HTML5Shiv/Modernizer?

Comment: Maybe... if it feels like it.  You might have a funky tag/not closed that's causing modernizr to not work right.  For a production type webpage, I'd not expect it to work *at all*.

Comment: I found the prob, I forgot to put modernizer in the `<head>` I had it just b4 end of `<body>`

Comment: @jiewmeng cool, glad it was something easy.  With that much JS going on, I'd recommend trying it on a slower PC before you release it to the wild.  IE's JS engine really stinks for people with old hardware.